# Extend DeserializeObject in Json.NET into a Try method

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I have been beating myself trying to figure out how to extend the generic method

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(value As String)
```

I am trying to write a extension that would return `Nothing` if the deserialization failed. Ideally:

```
JsonConvert.TryDeserializeObject(Of T)(value As String)
```

Comment: and the code you've try tus far is...?

Comment: Extension methods work on class instances, so this won't be possible. You'll have to create your own `JsonHelpers` class or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that by extension that you did not mean an actual `Extension`, rather a way to extend `Newtonsoft.JsonConvert`.

- An actual extension requires an instance object.  JsonConvert is a Type with all shared/static members, so that wont work.
- Nor can you extend the class by inheriting it because it is a sealed class (not inheritable).

The closest thing would be a string extension method:

```
<Extension>
Public Function JsonTryDeserialize(Of T)(json As String) As T

    Dim obj As T

    Try
        obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(json)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

    Return CType(obj, T)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim jstr As String = ...json string from somewhere
Dim myFoo = jstr.JsonTryDeserialize(Of Foo)()
```

Personally, I think the *best* place for it is in the Type you are working with as a shared function; its more applicable, matches the other Json methods the code is simpler and Intellisence is not cluttered:

```
Class Foo
   ... stuff

    Public Shared Function JsonTryDeserialize(json As String) As Foo
        Dim f As Foo

        Try
            f = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Foo)(json)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try

        Return f
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
newFoo = Foo.JsonTryDeserialize(strJ)
```

Comment: Why not "Dim obj as T = Nothing", then squelch the exception when doing the conversion. If you just return obj, then you return either an object, or nothing.

Comment: you are right - I got ahead of myself in my head with how to create a new T() when the deserializer actually does that, good point!